# ¿Cómo puedo agregar la extensión Mysqli o Mysqlnd a mi contenedor docker con php 8.0?

Tags: php, mysqli, docker, extensiones

Este es el código de mi documento Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8-apache

COPY . /var/www/html
```

Al ejecutar `$conexion = $mysqlnd_connection = new MysqlndUhConnection();` me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MysqlndUhConnection' not found in /var/www/html/statics/php/db/Database.php

Al ejecutar `$conexion = mysqli_connect($this-> host, $this-> user, $this-> password) or die("No se ha podido conectar a MySQL");` me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/statics/php/db/Database.php

He buscado en internet la forma de poder hacerlo, pero han pasado las horas sin tener éxito,

He corrido el programa con xampp y me ha funcionado de maravilla, pero cuando ejecuto el contenedor docker me salen los errores antes mencionados.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, las imágenes de PHP vienen limpias de extensiones por lo que tienes que agregarla como se indica en la documentacion. Para MySQL añade al Dokerfile `RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli`. Aquí puedes ver una lista completa de extensiones disponibles para cada versión https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes ver  [la cap](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/8-apache/images/sha256-8b9f42dde527854af5457db62c9fa096f9db8d1b5e5dd6a5c58cddc7c2ec6069?context=explore) de php:8-apache no se incluye extensiones de apache

puedes instalar por

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Visto también un [proyecto de github](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) cuál te instala las extensiones que falta

Mira te pongo un ejemplo

```
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions mysqli
```

El primer paso es descargar el proyecto desde GitHub, luego dar permisos y por último instalar la extensión de MySQL